# Facebook session expiration error when try to post actions to open graph  using 'App access token' 

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-access-token

I am facing this error with some of my users, the case is as following:

I use facebook "App access token" to post actions to facebook Open Graph instead of the user access token because app access token don't expire according to facebook documentation unless you refreshed the app secret, I use the follwoing Post url to post actions

https://graph.facebook.com/user_facebook_id/App_Namespace:action_name?FBOG_Object=FBOG_OBJECT_URL&access_token=app_access_token

Some of the actions do appear on facebook, but for some users the actions fails to post and return the following message:

```
{ "error": { "message": "Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1345759200. The current unix time is 1345925578.", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 190, "error_subcode": 463 } }
```

What am I doing wrong? Why do I have an expiration error although am using the app access token? Should I worry for user permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking the servers it seems that the code that uses the app token was not deployed and the code that uses the user token is still there.

The app token does not expire unless the app owner took some action.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/

Answer (score 0):

Error message clearly shows that your access token expired and you need to get another one.

However you can handle this issue : [Access token expiration](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/)

Also if you are looking for a long life token you need to provide some more parameters while authorizing the application to a new user.

`offline_access` parameter can be included in a request but now it's been deprecated by facebook. [Removal of offline access](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)

Comment: This is the problem I use an app access token NOT user access token and it shouldn't expire according to facebook documentation.

Comment: Can you share the documentation

Comment: He's referring to the [App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) which should not expire. OP, are you SURE it's the app access token you're using?

Comment: it is an app access token and it is working properly now, it seems that my work was cached on the user access token every thing is working fine now, I need a way to close this question now because it is not valid